# Log-Cosh Loss Function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have read about loss functions theoretically and also how to build regression models based on them in R.

I can apply all of the regression models based on different loss functions in R programming except for Log-Cosh Loss Function.

For example, if I would like to build a linear regression model on full data, I will use something like this.

```
linearMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)  
print(linearMod)
```

The same for the rest of the regression models. However, I do not find any code or package to apply a regression model based on Log-Cosh Loss Function in R.

Could you please guide me to any source that would help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It's unclear what difficulty you have. Why is this any harder than any number of other functions?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica, I edited the question.